# Python 3 - Reading line by line from a textfile and doing action for each line

Tags: python, string, text, python-3.x, text-parsing

I need something like this done:

- Login to a website.
- Make an action to a specific URL.
- After the action, go to another URL (still in the site).

So far here's what I've done.

```
if loginAccount(user, pass, url) == 1:
    if someActionChecking(url) == 1:
        None
    else:
        print ("[INFO]blablabla")
        actionNow(url, actionProcess)

    if someActionChecking(url2) == 1:
        None
    else:
        print ("[INFO]blablabla")
        actionNow(url2, actionProcess)

    if someActionChecking(url3) == 1:
        None
    else:
        print ("[INFO]blablabla")
        actionNow(url3, actionProcess)
else:
    print ("Login failed.")
```

Now here's the **problem**:

I want to shorten the code and make my life easier by just fetching the url's from a text file that contains *url1, url2, url3* (as an example), read the URL's stored there line by line, and loop the **actionNow()** function per line. So it will be something like this:

```
if loginAccount(user, pass, url) == 1:
    if someActionChecking(url) == 1:
        None
    else:
        #I need to loop this process below!!
        print ("[INFO]blablabla")
        actionNow(url, actionProcess)
else:
    print ("Login failed.")
```

Any workaround for this? I am already searching for a couple of days now, and all I see was the **strip()** technique but I can't really understand how it works.

Hope someone can guide me,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
urlFile = "path/to/file"
urls = open(urlFile).readLines()

for url in urls:
  doAction(url)
```

OR you could just put it all in the url file reading loop;

```
with open(urlFile) as f:
  for line in f:
    doAction(line)
```

Comment: @will In the `with open(...)` option, you probably meant `doAction(line)` (alternatively, `for url in f:`)

Comment: @twalberg So i did! I was racing to get the answer out!!